# How can I redirect a std::ofstream to std::cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, cout, ofstream

I'm working with some code that uses a global debug logger that is of type `std::ofstream*`. I would like to redirect this to std::cout since I'm using the code in realtime, as opposed to a batch method for which it was designed.

Is it possible to redirect the global `std::ofstream*` pointer it uses to `std::cout`? I know `std::ofstream` inherits from `std::ios`, which allows one to change the stream buffer using the `rdbuf()` method, but unfortunately it appears `std::ofstream` redefines the `rdbuf()` method, which makes the following code not compile:

```
gOsTrace = new std::ofstream();
gOsTrace->rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

Is there another way to redirect the `gOsTrace` object to point to `cout`?

Comment: Does the logger have to use `std::ofstream*` Can it not be the more generic `std::ostream*`. Then all you to do is make an assignment to this pointer with the new stream.

Comment: std::ios::tie? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, All that does is flush it occasionally. For example, `std::cin` flushes `std::cout` when there's an input operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, because it's not my code (I'm just linking against it and have limited ability to make changes), I am reluctant to change the logger type, especially given that it is a global used in many places, so the short answer is no, the logger can't be the more generic std::ostream...

Comment: Your sample code is illegal, `new` gives a pointer but you then use `.` on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `rdbuf()` method of the concrete IOStream stream classes hide the one declared in `std::ios`. You will need an explicit qualification in order to find the base class overload:

```
gOsTrace->basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. It should be noted though, that it won't actually redirect to std::cout unless the ofstream successfully opens a file for writing. I.e. the default constructor as in my code will not redirect.